# Django - Is there a way to create a variable in the template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to do this:

```
{% for egg in eggs %}
    <p>{{ egg.spam }}</p>
    {% if egg.is_cool %}
        {% myvariable = egg %} // Possible in any way?
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Pardon the JavaScript-style comment (it shows up as a comment on SO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Django Templates.

This problem is easily solved with one of the earliest snippets posted to DjangoSnippets.com: the [Expr tag](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/).

People can argue all day about the separation of logic from the templates, but that ignores that there is *business logic*, which belongs in the models or views, and *presentation logic* which belongs *only* in the templates. If you have a lot of *presentation logic* you may want to consider using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) for some or all of your templates. WARNING: although Jinja2 *looks* a lot like Django's template language, there are incompatibilities with things like [Custom Template Tags](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.djangoproject.com%2Fen%2Fdev%2Fhowto%2Fcustom-template-tags%2F&ei=8UUJTNvLDpn4MtSI-bUE&usg=AFQjCNHGf_6lFWW94jlvPfDzZWn-Lw0V3A).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I've been considering using Cheetah, but never really thought about using Jinja. I think the reason is that I currently use Velocity, but now that I'm accustomed to using Django templates' style and syntax, Jinja might be a fine addition.

Answer (score 3):

I think the closest you'll get is the `with` tag: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with.

If you're say trying to feature an item in a template, I can imagine doing something like:

```
<div class="special">
{% with some_list.first as special_item %}
    {{ specialitem }}
{% endwith %}
</div>

<div class="everything">
{% for item in some_list %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

If you want some special logic to determine which one is the special item, I'd add a method to the object (so you end up with: `{% with some_collection.my_method as special_item %}` above) or determine the special item before passing it to the view.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Basically, the reason for creating a variable is to use it outside of the loop. The `with` tag is a loop itself. I need to later access `myvariable` later in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [`with`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) construct:

```
{% with myvariable as egg %}
do stuf
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: The only problem is: `The populated variable (in the example above, total) is only available between the {% with %} and {% endwith %} tags.`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably best to do this kind of test-and-set behaviour in the view, not the template. If anything, it'll give you better control over cacheing if/when you need it.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that I need to do this in all of my views.

Comment: if you really need to do it in ALL of your views you could create a decorator or some middleware to encapsulate whatever the logic is that you need.